# How to calculate the intersection area on BitmapImage composition in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I am trying to merge two `BitmapImage`'s into one composite image. But some parts are overlaping each other .

```
var green = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\temp\green.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var red = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\temp\red.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

var visual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingImage drawingImageSource;
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
{
  DrawingGroup imageDrawings = new DrawingGroup();

  imageDrawings.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(red, new Rect(0, 0, red.PixelWidth, red.PixelHeight)));
  imageDrawings.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(green, new Rect(red.PixelWidth - 10, red.PixelHeight - 10, green.PixelWidth, green.PixelHeight)));

  drawingImageSource = new DrawingImage(imageDrawings);

  RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(red.PixelWidth + green.PixelWidth - offsetX, red.PixelHeight + green.PixelHeight - offsetY, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
  bmp.Render(visual);

  //no binding, just my image control to keep it simple
  this.fImage.Source = drawingImageSource;        
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
  <Image x:Name="fImage"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to render the intersection area in different ways, e.g. mix the colors or gradient based transition. Are there some instruments in .NET or do I need to handle with pixels?

Comment: Please improve your sample code, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Updated the code